# Testing with Optional Import in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-import

I have a library that can use two modules; one is fast but available only on Linux and macOS, the other is slower but it's multi-platform. My solution was to make the library compatible with both and have something like the following:

```py
try:
    import fastmodule
except ImportError:
    import slowmodule
```

Now I want to compare the timing of the library when using either module. Is there any way of masking the `fastmodule` without changing the source code (i.e. within a Jupyter Notebook), in an environment where both modules are installed, so that the  `slowmodule` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but here it goes:
You can write your own importer and register it (note that this is Python 3-specific, Python 2 had another API for this):

```
import sut
import functools
import importlib
import sys


def use_slow(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        ImportRaiser.use_slow = True
        if 'fastmodule' in sys.modules:
            del sys.modules['fastmodule']  # otherwise it will remain cached
        importlib.reload(sut)
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


def use_fast(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        ImportRaiser.use_slow = False
        importlib.reload(sut)
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


class ImportRaiser:
    use_slow = False

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if fullname == 'fastmodule':
            if self.use_slow:
                raise ImportError()


sys.meta_path.insert(0, ImportRaiser())

@use_fast
def test_fast():
    # test code


@use_slow
def test_slow():
    # test code
```

Here, `sut` is your module under test, which you have to reload in order to change the behavior. I added decorators for readabilty, but this can be done by some function or in the test setup, of course.

If you use the slow version, `fastmodule` will raise `ImportError` on import and `slowmodule` will be used instead. In "fast" case, all works as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the trick, but this does not seem to be called at all...

Comment: Actually, this works perfectly if I didn't load my package previously. I tried to use `importlib.reload` but didn't work. Is there a way to make this work within a single script where I want to run with both `fastmodule` and `slowmodule` in order to aggregate the data?

Comment: I extended the answer a bit to show how to use both `slowmodule` and `fastmodule` in your test. Admittedly not the nicest code, but it should work (I tested it with some dummy code).

Comment: Thanks! `del sys.modules['fastmodule']` was the missing step! =)